# Servicestack 4.5.4 AutoBatch requests failed validation

Tags: servicestack

We are writing an api that imports data from a spreadsheet. We have a create endpoint that we are using the Auto Batched feature, because we want to make one call from the UI rather than one call per row. We were hoping we wouldn't have to implement a specific endpoint and validator for a BulkCreate and could use the AutoBatch feature of service stack. We have run into an issue where if one request fails validation it stops running through the rest of the requests and returns the exception to the client. Is there a way to configure or work around this functionality? Our ideal scenario would be that we can send the array of requests and get back an array of responses, which contained either a successful response or the populated ResponseStatus without it turning into an exception in the client without having to custom write the whole slice without using auto batch.

```
[Route("/items/")]
public class CreateItem : IReturn<CreateItemResponse>
{
    public Item Item {get;set;}
}


public class CreateItemResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
   public int ItemId {get;set;}
   public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus {get;set;}
}
```

Illustrative, the nested rules would be in their own validator that is set as a child

```
public class CreateItemValidator: AbstractValidator<CreateItem>
{
    public CreateItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(request => request.Item.PropA)
            .Must(someRuleThatFailsSometimes);
    }
}
```

Service

```
public class ItemService : Service
{
    public CreateItemResponse Any(CreateItem request)
    {
        CreateItem(request);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior of AutoBatched Requests where it will short-circuit and return the first Exception. It also sets the `X-AutoBatch-Completed` HTTP Header (HttpHeaders.XAutoBatchCompleted) to the number of requests completed.

To change the behavior you would need to override it [Custom Batched Request Implementation](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-batched-requests#custom-batched-requests-implementations) which will let you control the behavior.

```
public CreateItemResponse Any(CreateItem[] requests) { ... }
```

Alternatively you could create your own batched Service by inheriting `List<T>`, e.g:

```
public class CreateItems : List<CreateItem>, IReturn<CreateItemsResponse>
{
    public Item[] Items {get;set;}
}
```

> Note: you shouldn't have trailing `/` in your Routes, i.e. just use `/items` intead of `/items/`.

Comment: I'm curious as to the reasoning behind the short circuiting behavior. Because of this, it means we essentially can't use auto batch in any of our services and will always need to send requests one at a time or implement our own batching. Obviously I'm coming from certain types of use cases, was the short circuiting intentional or more a product of other design decisions?

Comment: @Dstum There's no way to return multiple Error Responses to indicate which ones have failed, i.e. the Exception thrown has to populate a single `ResponseStatus` property.